# OWASP ZAP - Initiated ZAP Daemon instance is not shutting down via Python after scan in Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: python, git, gitlab, owasp, zap

## Initiating ZAP through Gitlab CLI as a Daemon

java -jar app.jar -daemon -dir $(pwd) &

## Running the scan through python and Report is generated

## After the scan completion, the Gitlab Linux box is still saying ZAPHost is listening on localhost:8080

I tried the zap.core.shutdown() but core is not being recognised at all even though all the necessary packages are installed.

Is running the ZAP as a daemon a problem since I am trying to shut it down from the python script?

Comment: What does this have to do with Git?

Answer (score 2):

That API call should do the trick. Are any other API calls failing? Are there any errors in the zap.log file?

Comment: No API calls are failing. It worked in my local system where I initialised the ZAP GUI and core,shutdown() is working but I am starting ZAP as a daemon here in Git Linux Box.

Should I do anything different if I have to shutdown the ZAP Dameon from my Python script. The same code is working on my local system.

Comment: #my .sh file which triggers the zap application headless(as a daemon):
java -jar  zap-2.8.0.jar -daemon -dir $(pwd)

Comment: We dont recommend running the jar directly - you should use the zap.sh script. Are you trying to access the API remotely or from the same box?

Comment: It is from the same box. I am running these commands serially:
1.) run zap.jar as daemon
2.) run the python script in the same box

Comment: I have gotten the zap.sh(only this file) and am trying to execute the same in Gitlab box but it says "Unable to access jar file even though the location is correct. Any more changes to be done in the zap.sh file?

Comment: The zap.sh file is a small wrapper, its useless on its own. You need a full ZAP installation in order to run ZAP.

Comment: While, I am running the zap.sh file successfully, I am not able to shutdown the daemon with a python script.

-chmod u+x zap.sh %% ./zap.sh -daemon -dir $(pwd)
- python3 scan.py

scan.py has my shutdown call